# Taylor expansion of $\frac{ \cos( \ln (n+1))}{(n+1)^{1/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Taylor Series Expansion of$$\frac{ \cos( \ln (n+1))}{(n+1)^{1/2}}$$

My try-

$$\cos(\ln (n+1))= \cos\left (\ln \ n+ \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$$$=\cos (\ln\  n) \cos\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)-\sin(\ln \ n)\sin\left(\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) $$
How to proceed?

Comment: @Mathlover any ideas?

Comment: Would you like to expand about $n=0$ or $+\infty$?

Comment: @Gary about n=$\infty$

Comment: You cannot have a Taylor expansion at infinity because the function is not analytic at infinity.

Comment: @Gary Then taylor expansion around 0?

Comment: @Gary See Wolfram Alpha gives an expansion at 0 and infinity

Comment: @Gary https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+cos%28ln+%28n%2B1%29%29%2F%28n%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29

Comment: The expansion about infinity given by Wolfram Alpha is not a Taylor series. A Taylor series about infinity would be a power series in $1/n$. The one by WA contains $\log n$'s.

Comment: @Gary Then please answer about $n=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $x=0$, we have
$$
\log (x + 1) = x - \frac{1}{2}x^2  + \frac{1}{3}x^3  -  \cdots ,
$$
$$
\cos (x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2  +  \cdots
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt {x + 1} }} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{8}x^2  -\frac{5}{16}x^3 + \cdots .
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
& \frac{{\cos (\log (x + 1))}}{{\sqrt {x + 1} }} = \\ &= \left( {1 - \frac{1}{2}\left( {x - \frac{1}{2}x^2  + \frac{1}{3}x^3  -  \cdots } \right)^2  +  \cdots } \right)\left( {1 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{8}x^2  - \frac{5}{{16}}x^3  +  \cdots } \right)
\\ &
 = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x - \frac{1}{8}x^2  + \frac{7}{{16}}x^3  +  \cdots .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. ! Thank you so much